# segmentation fault in C++ I don't get

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind

The following program results in a segmentation error when being run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct schokolade
{
    char name[20];
    int gewicht;
    int zutat_id[5];
    int menge_in_prozent[5];
};

struct zutat
{
    char name[20];
    float preis_pro_100gramm;
};


int main()
{
    char data[20];
    schokolade schokosorten[3];
    zutat zutaten[7];

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("schoki.txt");
    //Check for error:
    if(fin.fail()){
        cout << "Datei schoki.txt konnte nicht geöffnet werden." << endl;
        return 0;
    }


    int anzahl;
    char name_zutat[20];
    int anteil;


    while(fin.getline(data,20)){

        if(strcmp(data, "vollmilch_mandel")==0){
            strcpy(schokosorten[0].name, data);
            fin >> schokosorten[0].gewicht;
            fin >> anzahl;

            for(int i=0;i<anzahl;i++){
                fin >> name_zutat >> anteil;
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "mandeln")==0){
                    schokosorten[0].zutat_id[i]=0;
                    schokosorten[0].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "marzipan")==0){
                    schokosorten[0].zutat_id[i]=1;
                    schokosorten[0].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "milchpulver")==0){
                    schokosorten[0].zutat_id[i]=2;
                    schokosorten[0].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "kakao")==0){
                    schokosorten[0].zutat_id[i]=3;
                    schokosorten[0].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "kakaobutter")==0){
                    schokosorten[0].zutat_id[i]=4;
                    schokosorten[0].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "keks")==0){
                    schokosorten[0].zutat_id[i]=5;
                    schokosorten[0].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "zucker")==0){
                    schokosorten[0].zutat_id[i]=6;
                    schokosorten[0].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }

            }

        }

        if(strcmp(data, "marzipan")==0){
            strcpy(schokosorten[1].name, data);
            fin >> schokosorten[1].gewicht;
            fin >> anzahl;

            for(int i=0;i<anzahl;i++){
                fin >> name_zutat >> anteil;
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "mandeln")==0){
                    schokosorten[1].zutat_id[i]=0;
                    schokosorten[1].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "marzipan")==0){
                    schokosorten[1].zutat_id[i]=1;
                    schokosorten[1].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "milchpulver")==0){
                    schokosorten[1].zutat_id[i]=2;
                    schokosorten[1].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "kakao")==0){
                    schokosorten[1].zutat_id[i]=3;
                    schokosorten[1].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "kakaobutter")==0){
                    schokosorten[1].zutat_id[i]=4;
                    schokosorten[1].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "keks")==0){
                    schokosorten[1].zutat_id[i]=5;
                    schokosorten[1].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "zucker")==0){
                    schokosorten[1].zutat_id[i]=6;
                    schokosorten[1].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }

            }
            schokosorten[1].zutat_id[anzahl]=-1;
        }

        if(strcmp(data, "keksschoki")==0){
            strcpy(schokosorten[2].name, data);
            fin >> schokosorten[2].gewicht;
            fin >> anzahl;

            for(int i=0;i<anzahl;i++){
                fin >> name_zutat >> anteil;
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "mandeln")==0){
                    schokosorten[2].zutat_id[i]=0;
                    schokosorten[2].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "marzipan")==0){
                    schokosorten[2].zutat_id[i]=1;
                    schokosorten[2].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "milchpulver")==0){
                    schokosorten[2].zutat_id[i]=2;
                    schokosorten[2].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "kakao")==0){
                    schokosorten[2].zutat_id[i]=3;
                    schokosorten[2].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "kakaobutter")==0){
                    schokosorten[2].zutat_id[i]=4;
                    schokosorten[2].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "keks")==0){
                    schokosorten[2].zutat_id[i]=5;
                    schokosorten[2].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }
                if(strcmp(name_zutat, "zucker")==0){
                    schokosorten[2].zutat_id[i]=6;
                    schokosorten[2].menge_in_prozent[i]= anteil;
                    continue;
                }

            }

        }

    }

    fin.close();


    fin.open("zutaten.txt");
    //Check for error:
    if(fin.fail()){
        cout << "Datei zutaten.txt konnte nicht geöffnet werden." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        fin >> zutaten[i].name;
        fin >> zutaten[i].preis_pro_100gramm;
    }

    fin.close();

//*******************Problem area starts here **************************
    float R_Kosten_0 = 0.0;

    for(int i=0; i<5 && schokosorten[0].zutat_id[i]!=-1; i++){
        R_Kosten_0 += zutaten[schokosorten[0].zutat_id[i]].preis_pro_100gramm * schokosorten[0].menge_in_prozent[i]/100.0;
    }

    float R_Kosten_1 = 0.0;

    for(int i=0; i<5 && schokosorten[1].zutat_id[i]!=-1; i++){
        R_Kosten_1 += zutaten[schokosorten[1].zutat_id[i]].preis_pro_100gramm * schokosorten[1].menge_in_prozent[i]/100.0;
    }

    float R_Kosten_2 = 0.0;

    for(int i=0; i<5 && schokosorten[2].zutat_id[i]!=-1; i++){
        R_Kosten_2 += zutaten[schokosorten[2].zutat_id[i]].preis_pro_100gramm * schokosorten[2].menge_in_prozent[i]/100.0;
    }
 //*******************Problem area ends here **************************

    return 0;
}
```

I first tried to use valgrind on it, which gave me the following hints:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==21457==    at 0x401B4E: main (in /root/Desktop/Beleg2)
==21457==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==21457==    at 0x401108: main (in /root/Desktop/Beleg2)
==21457== 
==21457== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==21457==    at 0x401AF7: main (in /root/Desktop/Beleg2)
==21457==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==21457==    at 0x401108: main (in /root/Desktop/Beleg2)
==21457== 
==21457== Invalid read of size 4
==21457==    at 0x401AF7: main (in /root/Desktop/Beleg2)
==21457==  Address 0x105f15c5a4 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I did not understand these hints, so I successively commented out certain parts of the code. Through this method, I came to the conclusion that the segmentation fault must be caused in a certain part of the code, which I have marked (see above).

However, I simply do not get what's going wrong in this part of the code. For me, it looks perfectly fine.

Does anybody of you understand what's up here?

---

Here's the content of the file schoki.txt:

```
vollmilch_mandel
100
5
kakao 34
kakaobutter 10
milchpulver 20
zucker 28
mandeln 8

marzipan
100
3
kakao 50
zucker 25
marzipan 25

keksschoki
100
5
kakao 40
mandeln 7
kakaobutter 8
zucker 30
keks 15
```

---

Here's  the content of the file zutaten.txt:

```
mandeln 1.10
marzipan 1.22
milchpulver 0.6
kakao 0.82
kakaobutter 2.2
keks 0.64
zucker 0.14
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You claim this is C++, but the code is basically C. You might want to look into some things like `std::string` and collections, and you'll probably get rid of the segfault in the process.

Comment: `...zutat_id[i]!=-1 && i<5` - the array access will happen with `i==5`.

Comment: Also, don't just identify problematic code, make it a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Mat why will zutat_id[i]!=-1 && i<5 the array be accessed at i==5? it should only access until i==4

Comment: Counterquestion: Why do you assume it does not?

Comment: I think I get it .... I have to reverse the conditions, don't I ?
i<5 && zutat_id[i]!=-1 will be fine ... I'll check it

Comment: Yep, in the future please consult your [Gummiente](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and break it down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Especially the latter should have been enough for you to solve it yourself.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code but I still get the segmentation fault ... I don't get why

Comment: my code now says  "for(int i=0; i<5 && schokosorten[0].zutat_id[i]!=-1; i++){..." so the array should be accessed only until i<=4 ... but I still get the segementation error when running the program ...

Comment: In addition to Biffen, you might also want to replace the arrays by std::vector. I'd also use an enum instead of IDs, like enum ingredient { almonds = 0, ... }. This is another weak spot by the way: You use ingredient names in your input file and tie them to certain IDs and then you read in ingredient name. If the ingredient list would be changed in order, the wrong ingredients would be used. By the way, always code in english. Output and input may of course be in some other language, but variable names et cetera should always be in english, allows for example people on SO to understand what

Comment: your code is supposed to do. Another thing, your program has far too big blocks. Your main should have only a few lines that call another function and your functions should be segmented. You could have written something like int id_of_ingredient_name(const string ingredient_name) and then use it in your first for loop, resulting in a far shorter code. Same goes for the other for loops. Big advantage of segmenting the code is that it gets far easier to find bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You will do better if you make sure the structures are initialized to 0 before using them.

```
schokolade schokosorten[3];
zutat zutaten[7];
```

easiest is to add a default constructor your structures that initializes all members

e.g.

```
struct zutat
{
    char name[20];
    float preis_pro_100gramm;
    zutat() : name(""),preis_pro_100gramm(0.0f) 
    {}
};
```

You are loading the file and assume that the contents will match your structure but if one of them is missing then it will remain uninitialized.

You should also do some bounds checking e.g. make sure anzahl smaller than your arrays.

Another thing: it is good to split up your function into several functions, it makes it easier to read and less prone to error.